# How to create a new table in drupal without uninstall/installing the custom module

Tags: installation

In my requirement i want to create new table without uninstalling and installing the module.. is there any way to do it...?

Comment: are you creating a custom module, or trying to change the behaviour of an existing module?

Comment: i have already created a custom module in that i want to create new table with the same schema of existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to simply implement [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) and manually add the table that you've added to `hook_schema()`:

```
/**
 * Add the foo table.
 */ 
function MYMODULE_update_7100() {
  $table_name = 'table_name';
  $schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('MYMODULE', $table_name);
  db_create_table($table_name, $schema);

  return $table_name . ' table created.';
}
```

That goes in your module's .install file along with the schema hook, and you'll need to run `drush updb` (or run through the UI at /update.php) for the changes to take effect.

Comment: as i am new to druapl one doubt in this, where i should place function MYMODULE_update_7100() and i am having schema of one table (already exists in database) now i am going to create new table with same schema but with new name (adding suffix to that).

Comment: Every table you want to exist needs its own entry in `hook_schema()`. Just add `$schema['table_new'] = $schema['original_table'];` if you want a copy, but make sure it's listed as its own separate thing. Then use `original_table` as the `$table_name` in the above code. I'd recommend reading the linked documentation, it'll answer a lot of your questions. The hook goes in the .install file, though

Answer (score 0):

You can create any table you want in any database with your favourite database management tool such as *phpMyAdmin*. How you do it is explained on [this page](http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/ss/create_tables.htm), but to summarize:

After you've logged in on *phpMyAdmin*, on the left hand side you will see "phpMyAdmin" logo, some small icons, and below them you will see your database name. Click on the name of the Drupal database (you can find its name in `settings.php` if you don't know what name it has). On the right hand side any tables you may have in your database will be displayed, as well as a box labeled "Create new table on database"

Click this and create the table you want.  You can then proceed to populate the table with the fields you need.

Or just create the table by way of the command line interface to the datebase.

Comment: I have tried in that way which is not worked...I think in drupal tables are interlinked with other custom tables right..

Comment: @Surender32253, I do this all the time.  This is how I create new tables when I am prototyping a new module.  I only export the schema to the `.install` file when I'm done prototyping. If it does not work for you, you're not doing it right. I've no idea what you means by "drupal tables are interlinked with other custom tables".  There is nothing special about the tables in a Drupal database.

Comment: Creating tables manually is (quite a bit) less desirable then using the API really. This will work, but for the sake of a few lines of code it's probably better to stay within best-practice

Comment: @Clive, I think it depends on the use case (which the OP has not told us). I use the API when the schema changes is going to be shared with others, or when they're going to be deployed on a production site. I do it manually when prototyping and just trying out stuff on a dev site. I may have misunderstood the requirement, but I assumed the "not installing the module"-provision in the question meant that the OP did *not* want to place a `hook_update_N` in the `.install`.

Comment: I think _"i want to create new table without uninstalling and installing the module"_ is a pretty clear use case ;) OP wants to use the schema API. But yeah, I guess for first-step prototyping on a new project you could get away with manually adding tables. I just see it wasted effort, as you're going to have to add them into code anyway to do any sort of useful Drupal-integrated testing. And when you're prototyping you'd just use devel/reinstall to clear out tables. Each to their own though!

Comment: Don't forget update hooks are just that - for _updates_, not _installs_. They just happen to go in the .install for bootstrap purposes

Comment: @Clive, you're probably much better than me in writing a correct schema from scratch. I tend to attract all sorts of DBO exceptions when I deploy an untested schema via the API. That's why I prefer creating it in the *phpMyAdmin* GUI, and then I export it and fix it in text when I am satisfied that it works.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying, that does make sense. Think I've just written _way_ too many `hook_schema()` implementations in my life, can't seem to get 'em wrong any more ;)